# Same Id for all the records using apex:commandLink

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference

I could not find the solution where I can assignTo value to a getter/setter in the controller

When hover over the commandLink I see the same Id for all the 30 records so the Id value i'm getting from the url rather coming from the Employees Id.

What I'm missing here?

```
    <apex:repeat value="{!Employees}" var="e" id="r">
    <apex:commandLink value="{!e.Name}" action="{!clickOnName}">
         <apex:param name="eId"
         value="{!e.Id}"
         assignTo="{!empId}"/>
    </apex:commandLink>
   </apex:repeat>
```

Controller:

```
public Id empId{get; set;}

public PageReference clickOnName() 
{
    system.debug('clickOnName//'  ); 
    PageReference newPage = Page.NewEmployee; 
    newPage.getParameters().put('empId', empId);  
    return newPage.setRedirect(true); 
}
```

Loading Employees:

```
public List<Employee__c> employees {get;set;}
List<Employee__c> employeeList = [soql_withsubquery];
List<Employee__c> newEmployeeList = new List<Employee__c>();
for(Employee__c e : employeeList ) {
    Employee__c emp = new Employee__c();
    emp.id = e.Id;
    ..... 
    newEmployeeList.add(e);
}
employees = newEmployeeList;
```

Comment: how is the controller getter for `{!Employees}` coded?

Comment: btw when I just have {!e.Id} in VFP I can see all correct Ids related to Employees

Comment: I updated my question typed from my phone.

Comment: "when I just have {!e.Id} in VFP I can see all correct Ids related to Employees", what does it mean?

Comment: Rendering on the vf page

Comment: can you use this: <apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="{!URLFOR($Page.NewEmployee/{!e.Id)}">
 {!e.Name}
 </apex:outputLink>

Comment: I could but how would you assign value to getter/setter property in my case  `empId`

Comment: Try using newEmployeeList.add(emp) ; instead of newEmployeeList.add(e);

Comment: it was a typo yes thats what i'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problems with passing the value, you can use `actionFunction` like this

> Without `assignTo` attribute:

**Visualforce**

```
<script>
function performOperation(param){
    clickOnAction(param);

}
</script>

<apex:actionFunction name="clickOnAction" action="{!clickOnName}" reRender="form1">
    <apex:param value="" name="empId"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:repeat value="{!Employees}" var="e" id="r">
    <apex:commandLink onclick=" return performOperation('{!e.id}')" value="{!e.Name}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

**Controller**

```
public PageReference clickOnName() 
{
    empId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('empId');
    system.debug('clickOnName//'  ); 
    PageReference newPage = Page.NewEmployee; 
    newPage.getParameters().put('empId', empId);  
    return newPage.setRedirect(true); 
}
```

> With `assignTo` attribute

```
<script>
function performOperation(param){
    clickOnAction(param);          
}
</script>

<apex:actionFunction name="clickOnAction" action="{!clickOnName}" reRender="form1">
        <apex:param value="" assignTo="{!empId}" name="empId"/>
    </apex:actionFunction>

<apex:repeat value="{!Employees}" var="e" id="r">
    <apex:commandLink onclick=" return performOperation('{!e.id}')" value="{!e.Name}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

**Controller**

You same code what you have written

Comment: tried both approaches i'm getting null...  system.debug  and `string  selectedId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('empId');`

Comment: can you change empId as String in controller

Comment: tried with `String` still the same `null`

Comment: just remove return false in javascript

Comment: if i remove the `return false` than its not redirecting to the `NewEmployee` stays on the same page.

Comment: is that value is getting passed?

Comment: the value is not passing, i did system.debug and `string selectedId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('empId');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52640/discussion-between-santanu-boral-and-nick-kahn).

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer...your getter+methods are far too complicated

```
public Employee__c[] employees {  // lazyload employees when requested by page or elsewhere in controller
  get { return employees == null 
                 ? employees = [some soql];
                 : employees;
      } set;
}
```

Comment: I have sub-query like master/detail, how will you do if you have sub-query the same code that you posted.

Comment: Nick -- the VF page you posted references the master - Employee__c so it will properly iterate over the employees retrieved in the SOQL, even if the SOQL has subquery. If your page had nested repeats, you could iterate over the children of each employee as well